# Set Calculated field that calculates difference of a date field and current datetime (Now function)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have 3 fields: `[CreatedDateTime]`, `[ClosedDateTime]` and `[TAT]`.
Default value of *CreatedDateTime* is `=Now()` so everytime a new record is added this field is auto-populated with the current *datetimestamp*.

Now the 3rd field needs to contain the running turn around time. 
While *CloseDateTime* is still empty, it should contain the difference of `Now()` and the `[CreatedDateTime]` field. Else it should contain the difference of `[ClosedDateTime]` and `[CreatedDateTime]`.

I tried using the *Calculated Field* type but it does not allow `Now()` as a function.
And so I tried *Before Change* event *Set Field* using below formula on the *Value field*:

```
IIF([ClosedDateTime]="",Now()-[CreatedDateTime],[ClosedDateTime]-[CreatedDateTime])
```

It accepts the formula but I get an error:

> Field Cannot be Update

Before I try anything else, is there a way to do this in Access?
Or maybe there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated fields **in tables** are a rather useless concept. See http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html

The solution is: Create a **query**, add the calculated field there, where the formula will work just fine, and then use the query instead of the table wherever you need the `TAT` field.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have no Form in Access. Instead I am just using it as database to store the values using OLEDB connection. I am using Excel VBA as front end. Or did I misunderstand what was discussed in the link you've provided. What I am trying to achieve is to have a field that re-calculates real time like a column in Excel where you can put a formula. Is it possible?

Comment: @L42: The frontend doesn't matter, be it an Access form or Excel. Calculated fields should never be part of a table, but calculated in a query (or in your case perhaps with an Excel formula when you output the data).

Comment: I get it now. So I'll just calculate when I retrieve the data. No way to make Access to behave like a Excel Spreadsheet with formulas that recalculates real time.

Comment: "store the Excel Formula in the field" - no, I meant to put the formula in the sheet where you display the data. Can you connect to an Access **query** via OLEDB? That would be the cleanest solution IMO.

Comment: Thanks Andre. I connect/query Access using OLEDB connection using ADODB. But yeah I get the idea. Actually, I've done what I need :).

Answer (score 0):

Use a textbox to calculate and display TAT with this *ControlSource*:

```
=Nz([ClosedDateTime],Now())-[CreatedDateTime]
```